# Looking for advice on setting up dual boot on new pc with ssd and hdd

Tags: dual-boot, ssd

I'm building a PC and plan on installing Win10 and Ubuntu.  I have a 1 TB SSD and 1 TB HDD.  I'm looking for any advice as I haven't done anything like this in ages.

Here is my current plan:
Install only the SSD at first.  Install Win10 on ssd.  Run PC through updates until Win10 is happy.  Resize partition to half of the SSD.  Physically install the HDD.  Partition the HDD into two parts.  First ntfs for Windows, probably 600 GB.  Move as much of MyDoc there are I can figure out how to (think it's under properties). Install Ubuntu on SSD, partitioning the second part of the HDD for /home.  Assume grub lives happily on sda (or whatever the ssd ends up being called.

Anyone see any issues with this plan?  I've been doing a lot of research, but I'm finding a lot of old info that may no longer apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your plan will work. The only thing, you'll have to consider: Ubuntu won't boot, if you're unplug your HDD, for Windows I don't know. (Yes, I tested it...)

But if I were you: Make the installation of Ubuntu before you save some data to the machine, because of the fact that there is always a probability that it could go wrong.

As for windows: Try to create your own installation Media with the Media Creaton Tool, because of the fact that then almost all updates are also installed.